# Очистка ComboBox в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Собственно, каким образом можно реализовать сабж, при csOwnerDrawFixed? Свойство Text не доступно.

Comment: Работает, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присвоить свойству `ItemIndex` значение `-1` не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть `ComboBox1.Items.Clear`?

Comment: Нет, немного не то. Этот код удаляет все значения ComboBoxб а мне нужен эффект, как от ComboBox.Text:='' при csDropDown. Т.е., удалить только видимую часть, а значения оставить.

Comment: Тогда проще сделать, как KoVadim написал.